# How to get most recent date based on a given date using python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Consider the following two dataframes:

Dataframe1 contains a list of users and stop_dates

[image]

Dataframe2 contains a history of user transactions and dates

[image]

I want to get the last transaction date before the stop date for all users in Dataframe1 (some users in Dataframe1 have multiple stop dates)

I want the output to look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Look at using `pd.merge_asof` with `on='Transaction_Date'` and `key='UserID'`.

Comment: [Don't include your data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code%20%28or%20error%2Fexception%20messages%2C,isn%27t%20available%20to%20those%20readers.%20...%20More%20items)

Answer (score 1):

Please always provide data in a form that makes it easy to use as samples (i.e. as text, not as images - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

You could try:

```py
df1["Stop_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Stop_Date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
df2["Transaction_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Transaction_Date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
df = (
    df1.merge(df2, on="UserID", how="left")
    .loc[lambda df: df["Stop_Date"] >= df["Transaction_Date"]]
    .groupby(["UserID", "Stop_Date"])["Transaction_Date"].max()
    .to_frame().reset_index().drop(columns="Stop_Date")
)
```

- Make `datetime`s out of the date columns.
- Merge `df2` on `df1` along `UserID`.
- Remove the rows which have a `Transaction_Date` greater than `Stop_Date`.
- Group the result by `UserID` and `Stop_Date,` and fetch the maximum `Transaction_Date`.
- Bring the result in shape.

Result for

`df1`:

```
   UserID Stop_Date
0       1    2/2/22
1       2    6/9/22
2       3   7/25/22
3       3   9/14/22
```

`df2`:

```
   UserID Transaction_Date
0       1           1/2/22
1       1           2/1/22
2       1           2/3/22
3       2          1/24/22
4       2          3/22/22
5       3          6/25/22
6       3          7/20/22
7       3          9/13/22
8       3          9/14/22
9       4           2/2/22
```

is

```
   UserID Transaction_Date
0       1       2022-02-01
1       2       2022-03-22
2       3       2022-07-20
3       3       2022-09-14
```

If you don't want to permanently change the `dtype` to `datetime`, and also want the result as string, similarly formatted as the input (with padding), then you could try:

```py
df = (
    df1
    .assign(Stop_Date=pd.to_datetime(df1["Stop_Date"], format="%m/%d/%y"))
    .merge(
        df2.assign(Transaction_Date=pd.to_datetime(df2["Transaction_Date"], format="%m/%d/%y")),
        on="UserID", how="left"
    )
    .loc[lambda df: df["Stop_Date"] >= df["Transaction_Date"]]
    .groupby(["UserID", "Stop_Date"])["Transaction_Date"].max()
    .to_frame().reset_index().drop(columns="Stop_Date")
    .assign(Transaction_Date=lambda df: df["Transaction_Date"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
)
```

Result:

```
   UserID Transaction_Date
0       1         02/01/22
1       2         03/22/22
2       3         07/20/22
3       3         09/14/22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish (make sure both date columns are already datetime):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="UserID")

df["Last_Before_Stop"] = df["Stop_Date"].apply(lambda x: max(df["Transaction_Date"][df["Transaction_Date"] <= x]))
```